# Component specific css files are not being loaded and/or applied in blazor web assembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In my blazor web assembly project I created a css file after component name.
Like Banner.razor.css(For Banner.razor component).

[image]

For example here is my Banner.razor:

```
<h1 class="reddish">Hello this is robin</h1>
```

and here is my Banner.razor.css

```
.reddish{
  color: red !important;
 }
```

The color is still black and no css class is found when I inspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing

```
<link href="AssemblyName.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in my index.html(inside wwwroot)

Comment: Also don't forget to rebuild the app after creating a new style file